# Install Apache server on 4G Network

Tags: apache, portforwarding, wan, 4g

I have installed **XAMPP** to run Apache server on windows,So the Apache server run great on **LAN** (*Local Area Network* ).

But i need to run the server ,so the public can access it from **WAN** 
(*Wide Area Network*) .

I have forward `HTTP port 80` on 4G  portable router ,but no device can access the Apache server from Public (WAN)

** I have tried **DDNS** solutions also with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely the 4g network itself. It seems they don't allow servers to wait on their network.